# My python build binaries not really running as 64bit program in AMD Win2003r2x64 machine

Tags: python, windows-server-2003, py2exe, pywin32, x86-64

My problem is
my python binaries not running as 64bits program on my amd64(Opteron 8214, 4 cpu) server.
The machine is a Dual-Core, so there are 8 core shown in taskmgr.
It shown no "*32" in taskmgr(so it probably already in 64bits mode), but use only one core.
And I take same code(project) to compiled and executed on an Intel Xeon machine, it will use all of processor core.

So how do I fix this? Anyone have some other idea? I need to make it running 64bit to use mutli-core to get job done ASAP. It's a data parser, it took most of runtime to parsing data records(via regex) then insert into mssql db.
Any comment is welcome. I've been working on this many weeks.

Official & third-party packages I used listed here.
python-2.7.1.amd64.msi
pywin32-214.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
pyodbc-2.1.8.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
py2exe-0.6.9.win64-py2.7.amd64.exe
wxPython2.8-win64-unicode-2.8.11.0-py27.exe
build binary via GUI2exe-0.5.0.zip

On Windows Server 2003 Standard x64 Edition SP2
I ever built exactly same code(project) on Intel Xeon CPU machine(win2003x64 of course),
And it was worked(**work means no "*32" tailing on process name of taskmgr, and also use each of CPU/Core**).

p.s. I cannot provide whole source code since it is a large project.

Comment: You'll have to provide something more than this. Is your problem that the process should use multiple cores and doesn't? The title does say that, but the body seems to.

Comment: My program need to run to end ASAP each time launched, so use multiple cores would be really helpful. The program is a data parser, will parsing some huge data binary file, for instance, load a 4GB file into mssql, it will took 40 seconds, but Xeon machine took only 18 seconds, and you can see each core are busy on taskmgr at the execution meanwhile, the Xeon machine only 4 cores and cpu freq. also not really much faster than this AMD machine, but code is exactly same, so I thought problem just because it use only one core. That's way. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the `subprocess` and `threading` modules that come with the standard Python library with regards to your multi-core issue. As for the 64bit issue, are you sure you need the additional memory space? I've never had any issue with 32bit python.